# Solidity to Java translator？Can we convert solidity file to Java file

Tags: java, ethereum, code-translation, solidity

Is there a tool out there that can automatically convert solidity to Java?And can we convent solidity file to java？

Answer (score 1):

Yes there's a tool called web3j for converting solidity to java. For using this on Windows

1.install npm
2.npm install web3j
3.install solidity 
Compile your smart contract in remix ide (online)and generate abi and save it to a new file namely contract_name.abi.

Also get the bytecode from remix and save it to a new file called contract _name.bin
Open command prompt and run the following command

web3j solidity generate contract _name.bin contract_name.abi -o out -p packagename

For running above command the .abi and .bin files must be in same directory.The output file will be in a folder "out".filename is contract_name.java.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no such tool as of now.

Comment: OK, I get it.Thanks